# How to optimally update cells based on previous cell value / How to elegantly spread values of cell to other cells?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a "large" DataFrame table with index being country codes (alpha-3) and columns being years (1900 to 2000) imported via a pd.read_csv(...) [as I understand, these are actually string so I need to pass it as '1945' for example].

The values are 0,1,2,3.
I need to "spread" these values until the next non-0 for each row.

- example : 0 0 1 0 0 3 0 0 2 1
- becomes: 0 0 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 1

I understand that I should not use iterations (current implementation is something like this, as you can see, using 2 loops is not optimal, I guess I could get rid of one by using apply(row) )

```
def spread_values(df):
    
    for idx in df.index:
    previous_v = 0
        for t_year in range(min_year, max_year):
            current_v = df.loc[idx, str(t_year)]
            if current_v == 0 and previous_v != 0:
                df.loc[idx, str(t_year)] = previous_v
            else:
                previous_v = current_v
```

However I am told I should use the apply() function, or vectorisation or list comprehension because it is not optimal?

The apply function however, regardless of the axis, does not allow to dynamically get the index/column (which I need to conditionally update the cell), and I think the core issue I can't make the vec or list options work is because I do **not** have a **finite set** of column names but rather a wide range (all examples I see use a handful of named columns...)

What would be the more **optimal** / more **elegant** solution here?

OR are DataFrames not suited for my data **at all**? what should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffil)`. This will fill all zeros in your dataframe (except for zeros occuring at the start of your dataframe) with the previous non-zero value per column.

If you want to do it `rowwise` unfortunately the `.replace()` function does not accept an `axis` argument. But you can `transpose` your `dataframe`, replace the zeros and `transpose` it again: `df.T.replace(0, method='ffill').T`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of this. I have implemented it and it seems to be replacing values vertically and not horizontally. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html doesn't show a parameter to change the axis?

Comment: I see, didn't notice that you intended to fill the zeros rowwise. Have edited my answer, to make it work.

Comment: I used a double transpose and it's working ;)
I just saw you also suggested that. Thanks! works like a charm